# No matching version found for loader-utils@undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Trying to install a project and the error that's coming up is as follows:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for loader-utils@undefined
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/nathan.hyland/.npm/_logs/2018-03-30T20_34_00_412Z-debug.log
```

In the log file, this is what's displayed:

```
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 silly install loadIdealTree
11 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
12 silly install loadShrinkwrap
13 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/loader-utils 289ms (from cache)
14 silly registry:manifest no matching version for loader-utils@undefined in the cache. Forcing revalidation
15 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/loader-utils 45ms (from cache)
16 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for loader-utils@latest No matching version found for loader-utils@undefined
17 silly saveTree redacted@0.1.0
17 silly saveTree ├─┬ @storybook/addon-actions@3.3.14
17 silly saveTree │ ├── deep-equal@1.0.1
17 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ global@4.3.2
17 silly saveTree │ │ ├─┬ min-document@2.19.0
17 silly saveTree │ │ │ └── dom-walk@0.1.1
17 silly saveTree │ │ └── process@0.5.2
17 silly saveTree │ ├── make-error@1.3.4
17 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ prop-types@15.6.0
17 silly saveTree │ │ ├─┬ fbjs@0.8.16
17 silly saveTree │ │ │ ├── core-js@1.2.7
------
... truncated for SO
------
17 silly saveTree │   ├─┬ inquirer@3.3.0
17 silly saveTree │   │ ├── ansi-escapes@3.0.0
17 silly saveTree │   │ ├─┬ chalk@2.3.0
17 silly saveTree │   │ │ ├── ansi-styles@3.2.0
17 silly saveTree │   │ │ └── supports-color@4.5.0
17 silly saveTree │   │ └─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0
17 silly saveTree │   │   └── ansi-regex@3.0.0
17 silly saveTree │   ├── is-root@1.0.0
17 silly saveTree │   ├─┬ opn@5.2.0
17 silly saveTree │   │ └── is-wsl@1.1.0
17 silly saveTree │   └── react-error-overlay@4.0.0
17 silly saveTree └─┬ react@15.6.2
17 silly saveTree   └── create-react-class@15.6.2
18 verbose type tag
19 verbose stack loader-utils: No matching version found for loader-utils@undefined
19 verbose stack     at pickManifest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/npm-pick-manifest/index.js:65:11)
19 verbose stack     at fetchPackument.then.packument (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/manifest.js:52:18)
19 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
19 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
19 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
19 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
19 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
19 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
19 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
19 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
19 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
19 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
19 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)
20 verbose cwd /Users/nathan.hyland/frontend/redacted/ui
21 verbose Darwin 16.7.0
22 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i"
23 verbose node v8.9.4
24 verbose npm  v5.8.0
25 error code ETARGET
26 error notarget No matching version found for loader-utils@undefined
27 error notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
27 error notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
28 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

What would cause this to not find an undefined version, or ask for an undefined version? This is a Create React App project, so a lot of the dependancies are hidden.